# When i'm trying to running geoserver web app in docker it is running but when i'm trying to login into the web app getting below error

Tags: java, spring, docker, jetty, geoserver

When I'm trying to run geoserver web app in Docker it is running but when I'm trying to login into the web app getting below error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this
    container for rendering: [Page class =
    org.geoserver.web.GeoServerHomePage, id = 1, render count = 1]  at
    org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1838)
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3921)
        at org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:801)     at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.internalPrepareForRender(Component.java:2236)
        at org.apache.wicket.Page.internalPrepareForRender(Page.java:242)
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2327)  at
    org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)   at
    org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)    at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)  at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create
    security/masterpw.digest    at
    org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore$FileSystemResource.file(FileSystemResourceStore.java:347)
        at
    org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore$FileSystemResource.out(FileSystemResourceStore.java:251)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.saveMasterPasswordDigest(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1714)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.computeAndSaveMasterPasswordDigest(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1723)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.loadMasterPasswordDigest(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1706)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.checkMasterPassword(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1685)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.checkMasterPassword(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1657)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.web.SecurityHomePageContentProvider$SecurityWarningsPanel.<init>(SecurityHomePageContentProvider.java:94)
        at
    org.geoserver.security.web.SecurityHomePageContentProvider.getPageBodyComponent(SecurityHomePageContentProvider.java:44)
        at
    org.geoserver.web.GeoServerHomePage$1.populateItem(GeoServerHomePage.java:133)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.onPopulate(ListView.java:523)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:124)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
        at
    org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1826)
        ... 134 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied  at
    java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)     at
    java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1014)  at
    org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore$FileSystemResource.file(FileSystemResourceStore.java:331)
        ... 148 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Cannot create `security/masterpw.digest`  
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
>  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1014)
>  at org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore...
> ```

You have file system permissions to work out in your docker image.

Comment: could please explain more because i have also get a same error

Comment: The user running geoserver in your docker image does not have permissions to create the file being reported.